# Cartesian product of Banach spaces: all norms such that the inclusion is an isometry are equivalent?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, norms

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an arbitrary (typically infinite-dimensional) Banach space with norm $\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{A}}$ and let $\mathcal{A}^{n}$ be its Cartesian product. I came across the following statement and wonder whether it is true or not:

All norms $\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{A}^{n}}$ on $\mathcal{A}^{n}$ such that $\|(0,...,0,\cdot,0,...,0)\|_{\mathcal{A}^{n}}=\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{A}}$ for all $i=1,...,n$ (i.e. the inclusion is an isometry) are equivalent.

It is clear that for every $x=(x_{1},...,x_{n})\in\mathcal{A}^{n}$ it holds:

\begin{equation} \|x\|_{\mathcal{A}^{n}}\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}\|x_{i}\|_{\mathcal{A}}=:\|x\|_{1}
\end{equation}

Therefore, $\|\cdot\|_{1}$ is stronger than $\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{A}^{n}}$.

What what about the other direction? Is it true?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 16):

It is actually not true in general that such a norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{\mathcal{A}^n}$ must be complete, despite the fact that the contrary is presented as fact in reputable sources in the literature (see, e.g., Section B.4.11 of Albrecht Pietsch's book *Operator Ideals* [the version published in 1980 by North-Holland] for the case $n=2$]).

A reference for the fact that $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{\mathcal{A}^n}$ need not be complete is the paper of Eve Oja and Peeter Oja, *On the completeness of Cartesian products of Banach spaces (in Russian)*. Acta et commentationes Universitatis Tartuensis, **661** (1984), 33−35. The English summary of the Oja-Oja paper can be read [here](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0587.46020).

I think the Oja-Oja paper is hard to come by, so when I learnt of its existence many years ago I believe I just derived my own example to satisfy myself. The Oja-Oja paper also notes that equivalence (hence also completeness) is assured when an additional condition is assumed. In particular it follows easily from the triangle inequality that if there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $$ \Vert (-x_1,\ldots,-x_{i-1},x_i,-x_{i+1},\ldots,-x_n)\Vert_{\mathcal{A}^n}\leq c \Vert (x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},x_i,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n)\Vert_{\mathcal{A}^n}$$ for all $x_1,\ldots, x_n\in\mathcal{A}$ then $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\mathcal{A}^n}$ is $(1+c)$-equivalent to the norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert_1$ as defined in your question.

(If I have time I might come back to this later and give some details of how to construct a counterexample, but I recall that it's not particularly difficult).

**Edit:** Bill Johnson's comment below notes a nice way of obtaining a counterexample.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know this!

Comment: Take $H$, $K$ to be quasi-complementary, non complementary subspaces of a Hilbert space $J$ and norm $H \oplus K$ with $\|(x,y)\| := \|x+y\|_J$.

Comment: @BillJohnson: thanks, Bill! That's a nice, simple way of stating a counterexample; I'd had a specific such counterexample in mind (i.e., of quasi-complemented, non-complemented subspaces of $\ell_2$), but hadn't thought about it in such general terms.

Comment: @NikWeaver: I seem to recall that I discovered it by accident, when trawling through Eve Oja's papers on Zentralblatt Math as a graduate student. I made a mental note of it at the time (*"the norm on a direct sum need not be 'like' a direct sum of norms"*), but haven't used it since - until now!